# How to count how many times I rolled a 0 before rolling a 1?

Tags: python

I've tried making a program that'd roll a dice that consists of 10000 sides (imagine it) and count how many times in a row the number rolled was below 4875, before being more than 4875. The number that represents how many times in a row such number was rolled isn't supposed to be greater than 16. I can't get the part displaying how many times in a row such thing occured working. My code is very messy as I'm more a HTML/CSS guy rather than a programmer and I'm still a Python virgin... Thanks in advance!

```
 import random

 userRolls = int(input("Rolls: "))
 print("")

 reds = 0
 blacks = 0
 lost = 0
 compRolls = 0
 times = 0

 x1 = 0
 x2 = 0
 x3 = 0
 x4 = 0
 x5 = 0
 x6 = 0
 x7 = 0
 x8 = 0
 x9 = 0
 x10 = 0
 x11 = 0
 x12 = 0
 x13 = 0
 x14 = 0
 x15 = 0
 x16 = 0

 while compRolls < userRolls:

     compGen = random.randint(0,10000)
     if compGen < 4875:
         compGen = 0
     elif compGen > 5125:
         compGen = 1
     else:
         lost = lost + 1

     print(compGen)

     if compGen == 0:
         reds = reds + 1
         times = times + 1
     else:
         blacks = blacks + 1
         times = 0

     if times == 1:
         x1 = x1 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 2:
         x2 = x2 + 1
         x1 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 3:
         x3 = x3 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x1 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 4:
         x4 = x4 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x1 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 5:
         x5 = x5 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x1 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 6:
         x6 = x6 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x1 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 7:
         x7 = x7 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x1 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 8:
         x8 = x8 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x1 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 9:
         x9 = x9 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x1 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 10:
         x10 = x10 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x1 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 11:
         x11 = x11 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x1 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 12:
         x12 = x12 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x1 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 13:
         x13 = x13 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x1 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 14:
         x14 = x14 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x1 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 15:
         x15 = x15 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x1 = 0
         x16 = 0
     elif times == 16:
         x16 = x16 + 1
         x2 = 0
         x3 = 0
         x4 = 0
         x5 = 0
         x6 = 0
         x7 = 0
         x8 = 0
         x9 = 0
         x10 = 0
         x11 = 0
         x12 = 0
         x13 = 0
         x14 = 0
         x15 = 0
         x1 = 0
     else:
         pass

     compRolls = compRolls + 1

 print("")
 print("x1: ", x1)
 print("x2: ", x2)
 print("x3: ", x3)
 print("x4: ", x4)
 print("x5: ", x5)
 print("x6: ", x6)
 print("x7: ", x7)
 print("x8: ", x8)
 print("x9: ", x9)
 print("x10: ", x10)
 print("x11: ", x11)
 print("x12: ", x12)
 print("x13: ", x13)
 print("x14: ", x14)
 print("x15: ", x15)
 print("x16: ", x16)
 print("")
 print("Reds: ", reds)
 print("Blacks: ", blacks)
 print("Lost: ", lost)
```

Comment: What are `x1` ... `x16`?

Comment: Use a list! `x = [0]*16`; `x[times] += 1`, etc.

Comment: @Lutz Horn How many times in a row a number less than 4875 was rolled. 

If such number was rolled twice in a row, x2 should be set as 1. Then, no number less than 4875 was rolled. Then, a number less than 4875 was rolled twice again so x2 should be now set as 2...

Comment: @Benjamin I don't really know how to do it, you see... You don't have to write the entire code for me, just develop your comment so I understand what to do and I'll make the necessary changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but your code would be a lot cleaner if you used [a list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html). I don't exactly understand what you are looking for but I made an attempt at solving your issue. Feel free to comment if you have more questions :)

EDIT: Maybe you don't want to reset the list? Does this code do what you want it to? I'm still unsure as to what you are looking to do...

EDIT2: I think I know what you mean now.  I did some testing and this code should work. I don't understand what all the reds, lost and blacks stuff is, but I'm sure this is enough to get you where you want.

```
from random import randint

num_rolls = int(input("Rolls: "))
print()

# I still don't know why 16 is the number, but ok...
xs = [0]*16

threshold = 4875

in_a_row = 0

# Repeat this num_rolls times
for i in range(0, num_rolls):
    # As Sci Prog says, since this is a die, you want to generate a random number from 1 to 10000 (inclusive) I imagine
    r = randint(1, 10001)
    if r < threshold:
        in_a_row += 1
    else:
        in_a_row = 0

    if in_a_row > 0:
        xs[in_a_row - 1] += 1
        if in_a_row > 1:
            xs[in_a_row - 2] -= 1

print()
for i in range(0, 16):
    print("x{}: {}".format(i+1, xs[i]))
```

Note: <strike>I haven't actually tested this code and so I'm not sure if it will work, but again, I'm not even sure what you are looking for :D</strike> Hope this helps! :) (Also, this is my first response on stackoverflow, so I'm not sure how this works...)

Comment: It helps with shortening my code, but it doesn't really help me solve my problem (works the same way)...
http://i.imgur.com/qUy5R1W.png You see, in the program, the number lower than 4875 (set as 0) was rolled once in a row twice and it was rolled 3 times in a row once - the actual results, however, are incorrect...

Comment: I think that the reset() function doesn't work properly.

Comment: I changed it. Instead of resetting the whole array, instead I just incremented the correct x and decremented the previous x. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: It's better! But it still doesn't solve the problem... Maybe this screenshot will show you want I want to achieve: http://i.imgur.com/6nVjO7s.png (actual results on the left, expected results on the right)

Comment: I made it very minimalist, but I'm sure it's enough. I tested it and it should work. Tell me if it doesn't though :)

Comment: Thank you, it works! You not only made me solve the problem but also made me research the list and other Python functions, making my Python knowledge even wider! Thank you, again!
P.S. The number 16 is there because the rolling of the die is supposed to stop if the number below 4875 was rolled 16 times in a row, but I have it all programmed in JavaScript (which is in fact way easier than Python, but that's prbobably just because I'm familiar with it)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how the number 16 is crucial in this except you might want stop checking after 16 rolls. This code should do that:

```
import random

sides = 10000
threshold = 4875
num_rolls = 0
r = int(random.random() * sides)

while r < threshold and num_rolls < 16:
  num_rolls = num_rolls + 1
  r = int(random.random() * sides)

print(num_rolls)
```

Comment: The 16 limit doesn't have to be included in the program if that helps, anyways, thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions

1. When rolling a N-sided dice, use `randint(1,N)` not `randint(0,N)`.  For example, a standard 6 sided dice can yield 1,2,3,4,5 or 6, not 0.  (with a 10000-sided dice, the difference can be minimal)
2. In your definition, you do not specify what happens when the roll equals 4875.
3. Although the probabilities become small, there is no limit to how many rolls it can take before obtaining a number greater than 4875.  Use a `dict` if you want to perform multiple simulations.

To simulate your problem

```
from random import randint
THRESHOLD = 4875
DICE_SIZE = 10000
NB_SIMULATIONS = 100
def one_simulation():
  result = 0
  while randint(1,DICE_SIZE) < THRESHOLD:  # or <=                            
    result += 1
  return result

def simulations():
  result = {}
  max_rolls = 0
  for s in range(NB_SIMULATIONS):
    nr = one_simulation()
    result[nr] = 1 + result.get(nr,0)
    if nr > max_rolls:  
      max_rolls = nr
  #     
  for nr in range( max_rolls + 1 ):
    print ("%d: %d" % ( nr, result.get(nr,0) ) )

simulations()
```

Comment: All of these suggestions are great, but no matter what I do, I can't get the code you wrote to work :/

Comment: Maybe this screenshot will show you want I want to achieve: http://i.imgur.com/6nVjO7s.png (actual results on the left, expected results on the right)

Comment: I just fixed a typo.  It should work for python2 and python3.